# Magento completely crashed after flushing cache

Tags: magento, caching

I'm new to Magento, but I managed to install Magento and also installed a new theme. While I was modifying and customizing Magento I needed to flush the cache (Magento itself suggested it). I had done this already twice, but the third time Magento completely crashed.

I have no idea what is gone wrong, but I cannot access the site anymore.

When I want to visit the frontend, the site finally resolves to an IP address that is completely unknow to me. Chrome also tells `This page is not available`. The IP / URL where the browser finally is pointing to is:

```
http://192.168.9.43/2013/11_12_552_5xx/mu_resp_1800_21670_571/
```

When visiting the backend, a login form is shown, but the markup is completely lost.

One of the errors in the browser console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT http://192.168.9.43/2013/11_12_552_5xx/mu_resp_1800_21670_571/skin/adminhtml/default/default/reset.css
```

So somehow it's continuously pointing to the mentioned IP address. What has gone wrong..?

When I remove the index.php file and replace it with some simple HTML, the site is just resolving under the domainname and all seems to be fine.
The IP address mentioned is not the IP addres fo the domainname.. looks like an internal IP.

Answer (score 0):

Oke, I found the problem!

I've bought an template and also imported the sample data. But after re-indexing, flushing and all other stuff Magento does, the base url (`web/unsecure/base_url`) was modified due to the sample date into the url `http://192.168.9.43/2013/11_12_552_5xx/mu_resp_1800_21670_571/`.

After I had the site working again, I also could not login into the admin, because the sample data also deleted all user accounts and put in their own user account! So now I also must try to fix this issue, but that's well written down on the internet!